# How to check email id is valid in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I used `Firebase authentication` in my android app. But in registration if I entered `abc@abc.com` it accept it successfully and also login the user successfully. But `abc@abc.com` in not real id. What is the way to check email id entered is really exist . e.g. `abhishekbuchake7@gmail.com` . This is my id provided by gmail. Please suggest

Answer (score 4):

To verify the email address using firebase, you can use the method `sendEmailVerification()`:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

user.sendEmailVerification()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
            }
        }
    });
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#sendEmailVerification()